# Can't import java class in lein repl

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

Trying to import java classes in a clojure project using lein, and subsequently use the main method to connect to TeamworkPM's API. :)

`project.clj`

```clj
(defproject teamwork "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    :description "FIXME: write description"
    :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
    :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
              :url  "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
    :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                   [clj-http "0.9.2"]]
    :resource-paths ["src/java/*"]
    :java-source-paths ["src/java/"]
    :javac-options ["-target" "1.6"
                    "-source" "1.6"
                    "-Xlint:-options"])
```

`TeamworkAPI.java` is located in `src/java/`.

```java
public class TeamworkAPI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        String APIKey = "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE";
        String TeamworkURL = "http://YOUR_TEAMWORKSITE_HERE.teamworkpm.net";

        try {
            URL url = new URL( TeamworkURL + "/projects.json" );
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            String userpassword = APIKey + ":" + "";
            String encodedAuthorization = Base64Coder.encodeString( userpassword );
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);
```

Then I fire up cider-jack-in on the correct project....

```
teamwork.core> (TeamworkAPI. new)

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: new in
   this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init133047100967026670.clj:1:1)
```

Trying to get my hands dirty with some of my first connectivity with foreign APIs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for making an object via interop is `(TeamworkAPI.)`, or the older `(new TeamworkAPI)`.

If you are trying to call that class' static main method: `(TeamworkAPI/main (into-array args))`

Comment: Marking as answered because you rock and answered the question to the title of the post.

Comment: When doing "(TeamworkAPI/main (into-aray args))" I raise "CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: TeamWorkAPI, compiling:(/tmp/form-init133047100967026670.clj:1:1)"

Comment: Doh, the "w" in "TeamworkAPI" was capitalized. When I fixed the case, this error was raised: "ClassNotFoundException TeamworkAPI.  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:366)"

Comment: Doh, I accidentally typed "(TeamworkAPI./main (into-array args))". It works!

Comment: `(import 'some.package.TeamWorkAPI)`, or refer to it by its full package qualified name. (editing my mistaken capitolizations, sorry)

Comment: completely unrelated -- what would I even want to pass in as an argument to the main function?

Comment: Just realized this is the second question of mine you have answered! Nice to see you again, noisesmith. Thank you for really helping me out.

Comment: `String[] args` is the standard signature for a `main` static method that can be run from the top level. Likely `main` is just implemented so it can be the main task of an app.